# Why application hungs when using 'count' keyword as localScope function name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have class Reservation in php Laravel 5. 
I create localScope query. 
When i use special word count, which is aggregate for sum in scope function name, my application hang up. 
When i change function name to something not like keyword like total, everything works fine. 
Why application hangs when i use special keyword ? How does process works. Stackoverflow ?

```
class Reservation extends Model
{
    public function scopecount($query){
      return $query->count();
    }
}
```

I return it as:

`$count = Reservation::currentMonth()->count();`

My function currentMonth:

```
public function scopecurrentMonth($query){
  return $query->where('date_from','>=', Carbon::now()->startOfMonth())
      ->where('date_to','<=', Carbon::now()->endOfMonth());
}
```

So why it hungs? 
When i change name count to total:

```
public function scopetotal($query){
    return $query->count();
}
```

and

```
$count = Reservation::currentMonth()->total();
```

everything works fine.

So why it hungs ?

Comment: Why would you use a scope for count()?

Comment: I was changing couple methods to localScopes and i had php count() somewhere, but for now i see that's not needed and total is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add a scope for `count()`, besides, it's already taken, unless you want to rename `count` to `total`?

You can just add `->count()` to your queries and it will return an `int`.